# How exactly are we supposed to kill K9 dogs in COD MW2?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

In Call of Duty Modern Warfare 2, K9 units (dogs) appear in some of the missions and the campaign. I sometimes manage to shoot and kill the K9 before it reaches me, but if that fails, the K9 jumps to me and I fall to the ground. In that scenario, the instruction is to press T (melee attack) to snap the neck of the K9, which seems pretty straightforward.

However, in reality this rarely seems to work. I have tried pressing T once once the K9 jumps and I fall to the ground, but to no avail. Then I pressed the T after *'Press T' warning* appeared, again didn't work. Then I tried spamming the T key, which didn't work either.

Is there a specific **time** and **a number of presses** of the T key are we supposed to follow, in order to kill the K9?

Comment: Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are talking about the campaign. I found out that if they are running at you, just shoot the K9 dogs. But if they jump on you, just mash the button on screen to snap its neck. But make sure you mash the button the moment they jump on you, or else it will be too late to kill them that way.